# Can I perform a Mypy assertion inside of a function that affects a primitive arg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Let's say I have a simple validation function:

```
def is_valid_build_target(target: Any, throw=False) -> bool:
    target = str(target)
    allowed_targets = ["dev", "prod"]
    is_allowed = target.lower() in ALLOWED_TARGETS
    if not is_allowed and throw:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Invalid target '{target}'. Must be one of: {ALLOWED_TARGETS}"
        )

    assert target is not None
    return is_allowed
```

But if I want to use this function, Mypy doesn't pass that assertion back up the stack (presumably because `target` is a primitive, and so Python localizes the variable to the function):

```
Target = Literal["dev", "prod"]
target: Target | None = cast(Target | None, os.getenv("APP_TARGET", None))

if not is_valid_build_target(target):
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid target, I could have used throw=True, but I wanted a custom error message")

# Mypy still thinks `target` could be None
```

If I do the function logic inline, or use the `assert` after, it then works, but now I'm not keeping the runtime validation logic in a self-contained function:

```
if not is_valid_build_target(target):
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid target...")
assert target is not None

# happy Mypy
```

Is there any way inside the validation function to validate this and keep Mypy happy?

Comment: Not directly related, but Python doesn't have the same arg passing semantics as Java.  Everything is a reference to an object, but only some objects are mutable.  See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Samwise if only Mypy knew that 

Comment: You probably want to use a type guard.

Comment: @Samwise so, the arg-passing semantics are exactly equivalent to the way reference types work in Java. And since "primitives" in Java are immutable, in effect, the evaluation strategy is "call by sharing", which is the same as many other languages (like Python). Just Java (I guess because it comes from a very C-like background and everything in it is supposed to be reminiscent of C/C++) says "call by value where the value is an object reference for reference types". This is the non-OO purity of Java rearing its head

Answer (score 1):

I would have your validation function do one of two things:

1. return the valid value, or
2. raise an exception

I would also check for `os.getenv` returning `None` first, as the variable not existing at all is a different problem (though one with the same possible solution) from having an invalid string value.

```
import typing
import os


Target = typing.Literal["dev", "prod"]
ALLOWED_TARGETS = typing.get_args(Target)

def valid_build_target(target: str) -> Target:
    lower_target = target.lower()
    if lower_target in ALLOWED_TARGETS:
        # It's a shame type narrowing doesn't work here.
        return typing.cast(Target, lower_target)
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Invalid target '{target}'. Must be one of: {ALLOWED_TARGETS}"
        )

possible_target = os.getenv("APP_TARGET")
if possible_target is None:
    raise ValueError("APP_TARGET not defined")

target: Target = valid_build_target(possible_target)
```

Even though `possible_target` initially has type `str | None`, by the time you call `valid_build_target` its type has been narrowed to `str`.

```
$ python3 tmp.py  # Raises
$ APP_TARGET= python3 tmp.py   # Raises
$ APP_TARGET=foo python3 tmp.py  # Raises
$ APP_TARGET=DEV python3 tmp.py  # OK
$ APP_TARGET=dev python3 tmp.py  # OK
```

Comment: I think the first option is fairly reasonable, overwriting the value instead – while a bit of a strange pattern, it addresses the Mypy issue and keeps the spirit of "I want to do all the validation inside the function". Having to do extra validation outside each time leaves a lot of room for mistakes.

Comment: Indeed, validation that only validates (without returning the same value as passed) is a common pattern, and I don't see anything wrong with it. You try to **validate**, not to convert/preprocess, it's perfectly fine to just return `bool` whether X is valid or raise if not valid. Toggling these two options with a boolean flag is more questionable, though. OP can use simple `TypeGuard` to keep their design unchanged, it already plays well with typing. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=4c50e88496e20c51e49c5d04a031d8ee

Comment: I interpreted your original question as something like `DEV` being acceptable as input (because it could be lowercased), but not as the final value for `target`. As such, I combined "validation" and "normalization" in a single function.

Comment: Technically, I never overwrote anything; `possible_target` is and remains a `str`, not a `Literal["dev", "foo"]`, value. I could have done `target = target.lower()` inside the function, because that didn't involve change the type. The name `lower_target` got left over from an attempt to allow `valid_build_target` accept an `Optional[str]` argument that I decided against in the end.